# How to Keep track of all clicks on page in ionic application?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

I have created simple page which contains check boxes. On this page user can check and uncheck boxes multiple times. I want to keep track of all these events? How Can I do that?

here is my code.

**app.js**

```
var pmApp = angular.module('pmApp', ['ionic']);

pmApp.controller('CheckboxController', function($scope) {
  $scope.devList = [
    { text: "Device & app history", details : "Allows the app to view one or more of: information about activity on the device, which apps are running, browsing history and bookmarks" ,checked: true },
    { text: "Identity", details: "Uses one or more of: accounts on the device, profile data", checked: false },
    { text: "Calendar", details: "Uses calendar information", checked: false },
    { text: "Contact", details: "Uses contact information", checked: false },
    { text: "Location", details: "Uses the device's location", checked: false },
    { text: "SMS", details: "Uses one or more of: SMS, MMS. Charges may apply.", checked: false }
  ];

  $scope.selection=[];
  // toggle selection for a given employee by name
  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(item) {
     var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(item);

     // is currently selected
     if (idx > -1) {
       $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
     }

     // is newly selected
     else {
       $scope.selection.push(item);
     }
   };

});
```

**index.html**

```
    <div class="list" ng-controller="CheckboxController">
        <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in devList"
                      ng-model="item.checked" 
                      ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item) > -1"
                      ng-click="toggleSelection(item)"
                      >
            {{ item.text }}
            <h3 class="item-text-wrap"> {{ item.details }}</h3>
        </ion-checkbox>
<div class="item">
          <pre ng-bind="selection | json"></pre> 
</div>
      </div>
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Where would you like to keep track of the triggered events and what would you want to keep track of exactly?

Comment: @mxa055 I would like to keep track of checkbox tick or untick mousehover events and button clicks of user. I want to keep these all track of triggered events with timestamp. I want to keep this tracked data on server side. How Can i put data on server side? Mongo DB or simple SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover to make a counter for mouse hovers on all your elements: and then use
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick to record clicks and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMousemove to record the mouse being moved and get the position:

Everything Used: 
    ng-click
    ng-dblclick
    ng-mousedown
    ng-mouseup
    ng-mouseenter
    ng-mouseleave
    ng-mousemove
    ng-mouseover

Here is some example code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="mainModule">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <h3>1. Click</h3>
    <button id="firstBtn" ng-click="onFirstBtnClick()">Click me</button>
    <strong>RESULT:</strong> {{onFirstBtnClickResult}}<br />
    <br />
    <h3>2. Click with Dependency Injection</h3>
    <label>Type something: <input type="text" ng-model="secondBtnInput"></label>
    <button id="secondBtn" ng-click="onSecondBtnClick(secondBtnInput)">Click me</button><br />
    <strong>RESULT:</strong> {{onSecondBtnClickResult}}<br />
    <br />
    <h3>3. Double click</h3>
    Double-click the square<br />
    <img src="images/square.png" ng-dblclick="onDblClick()" /><br />
    <strong>RESULT:</strong> {{onDblClickResult}}<br />
    <h3>4. Mouse down, up, enter, leave, move, over</h3>
    Move the mouse on the square<br />
    <img src="images/square.png"
         ng-mousedown="onMouseDown($event)"
         ng-mouseup="onMouseUp($event)"
         ng-mouseenter="onMouseEnter($event)"
         ng-mouseleave="onMouseLeave($event)"
         ng-mousemove="onMouseMove($event)"
         ng-mouseover="onMouseOver($event)" /><br />
    <strong>MOUSE DOWN RESULT:</strong> {{onMouseDownResult}}<br />
    <strong>MOUSE UP RESULT:</strong> {{onMouseUpResult}}<br />
    <strong>MOUSE ENTER RESULT:</strong> {{onMouseEnterResult}}<br />
    <strong>MOUSE LEAVE RESULT:</strong> {{onMouseLeaveResult}}<br />
    <strong>MOUSE MOVE RESULT:</strong> {{onMouseMoveResult}}<br />
    <strong>MOUSE OVER RESULT:</strong> {{onMouseOverResult}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
angular.module("mainModule", [])
  .controller("mainController", function ($scope)
  {
    // Initialization
    $scope.onFirstBtnClickResult = "";
    $scope.secondBtnInput = "";
    $scope.onDblClickResult = "";
    $scope.onMouseDownResult = "";
    $scope.onMouseUpResult = "";
    $scope.onMouseEnterResult = "";
    $scope.onMouseLeaveResult = "";
    $scope.onMouseMoveResult = "";
    $scope.onMouseOverResult = "";

    // Utility functions

    // Accepts a MouseEvent as input and returns the x and y
    // coordinates relative to the target element.
    var getCrossBrowserElementCoords = function (mouseEvent)
    {
      var result = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };

      if (!mouseEvent)
      {
        mouseEvent = window.event;
      }

      if (mouseEvent.pageX || mouseEvent.pageY)
      {
        result.x = mouseEvent.pageX;
        result.y = mouseEvent.pageY;
      }
      else if (mouseEvent.clientX || mouseEvent.clientY)
      {
        result.x = mouseEvent.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
          document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        result.y = mouseEvent.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
          document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      }

      if (mouseEvent.target)
      {
        var offEl = mouseEvent.target;
        var offX = 0;
        var offY = 0;

        if (typeof(offEl.offsetParent) != "undefined")
        {
          while (offEl)
          {
            offX += offEl.offsetLeft;
            offY += offEl.offsetTop;

            offEl = offEl.offsetParent;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          offX = offEl.x;
          offY = offEl.y;
        }

        result.x -= offX;
        result.y -= offY;
      }

      return result;
    };

    var getMouseEventResult = function (mouseEvent, mouseEventDesc)
    {
      var coords = getCrossBrowserElementCoords(mouseEvent);
      return mouseEventDesc + " at (" + coords.x + ", " + coords.y + ")";
    };

    // Event handlers
    $scope.onFirstBtnClick = function () {
      $scope.onFirstBtnClickResult = "CLICKED";
    };

    $scope.onSecondBtnClick = function (value) {
      $scope.onSecondBtnClickResult = "you typed '" + value + "'";
    };

    $scope.onDblClick = function () {
      $scope.onDblClickResult = "DOUBLE-CLICKED";
    };

    $scope.onMouseDown = function ($event) {
      $scope.onMouseDownResult = getMouseEventResult($event, "Mouse down");
    };

    $scope.onMouseUp = function ($event) {
      $scope.onMouseUpResult = getMouseEventResult($event, "Mouse up");
    };

    $scope.onMouseEnter = function ($event) {
      $scope.onMouseEnterResult = getMouseEventResult($event, "Mouse enter");
    };

    $scope.onMouseLeave = function ($event) {
      $scope.onMouseLeaveResult = getMouseEventResult($event, "Mouse leave");
    };

    $scope.onMouseMove = function ($event) {
      $scope.onMouseMoveResult = getMouseEventResult($event, "Mouse move");
    };

    $scope.onMouseOver = function ($event) {
      $scope.onMouseOverResult = getMouseEventResult($event, "Mouse over");
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the newest Ionic Analytics, if that will suit your needs. More info on their official blog post: http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/analytics-from-scratch.

Usage is pretty straight forward (from the [additional docs](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/analytics-tracking)):

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($ionicAnalytics) {

  $ionicAnalytics.track('Purchase Item', {
     item_id: 'lpdsx,
     item_name: 'Leopard Socks'
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already seen these all docs. How can i keep track of mousehover and checkbox check or uncheck events?