# Button click not open new page in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my code. I want to open a new page when user click on "Login" button. I already wrote config function and set state name also. Why my `"applicaion.html"` page is not opening.

In console I can see username print but `$state.go('apps')` line is not working.

```
[http://codepen.io/skpatel/pen/XbVjKJ][1]
[1]: http://codepen.io/skpatel/pen/XbVjKJ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this updated code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqEpbR?editors=101

You missed the following into index.html: add a reference to `ui-view` (from ui-router) that is managing the change of views.
Your code was static into index.html with no reference to new pages.

Ui-view has been added to index.html. This is [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) directive and is mandatory. Ionic uses ui-router

```
<body>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

I have put out code of login page into a script template :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
        <h1 class="title">Application Permissions</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content padding="true" has-header="true" padding="true" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        <p>Welcome to the privacy mirror home page!</p>
        <p>Enter your name and then you can just tap the login button to be logged in</p>
        <label class="item item-input" class="padding">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" required>
        </label>
        <div class="padding">
            <button class="button button-block button-stable" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</script>
```

And also created a `apps.html t`emplate:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="apps.html">

  THIS IS MY APP PAGE
</script>
```

Finally, there is the routing rules to update to point to home.html

```
  .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
```

Comment: Thanks Let me try my self

Comment: As per this tutorial its not compulsory to put `ui-view`. why ? I am totally new for this technology sorry for dumb questions

Comment: I have edited my response to include the ui-view part

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why you added this line :

`<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">`

Why I can not start direct from this line : <ion-view title="home" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

Comment: I referenced the template into the state.routing with templateUrl: 'home.html'. Therefore this file shall be defined somewhere. As I can not easily add a file into codepen, I have added a template that "simulate" a file.  ui-routing needs templates to proceed the states. You need to read more about ui-routing and States

Comment: I followed as you wrote above. But its not working. even I am not able to see home.html page also

Comment: Have you seen my updated CodePen ? it is working fine

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake in home.html. I should remove <script> tag when I put in file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81731/discussion-between-sam-k-and-aorfevre).

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Please take a look on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081842/how-to-keep-track-of-all-clicks-on-page-in-ionic-application